# Remove character and replace backslash from string

Tags: php, html

I am getting directory path in my PHP like below

```
C:\Users\MAITRII\Desktop\LATEST\a
```

using code like below

```
$path = getcwd();
```

Now I want **replace "\" with "/" and want remove C:** from string and want output like below

```
/Users/MAITRII/Desktop/LATEST/a
```

Let me know if someone can help me for achieve this.

Comment: Try it with [str_replace](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php).

Comment: use `str_replace` or use explode function like `explode("\",$path)` and use implode `implode("/", $path);`

Comment: If I use \ in str_replace its giving me error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per my comment Use `str_replace` function but in backslash case use this pattern `'\\', '/'`

```
<?php
$path="C:\Users\MAITRII\Desktop\LATEST\a";
$path = str_replace('\\', '/', $path);
print_r($path);
```

here is the [output](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/3896ebf473994c33ef005ba0960646af261f6dfe)

and finally you can remove `C:` using `substr` function

```
$path = substr($path, 2);
```

Answer (score 1):

please try

```
$path = 'C:\Users\MAITRII\Desktop\LATEST\a';
$path1 = substr($path, 2);
$path2 = str_replace("\\","/",$path1); 
echo $path2;
```

`subsrt` will remove first two letters i.e. `C:`

`str_replace` will replace \ with /

You will need to add additional `\` in `str_replace("\\","/",$path1);`

[OUTPUT is here](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/38ace0860eed8caf8c8ab99dd237a37ff7924c78)